# Get Client IP in Stateless EJB

Tags: java, web-services, ejb, stateless

I have Stateless EJB WebService.

WS interface:

```
@Remote  
@WebService
public interface WSInterface{  
    @WebMethod  
    public String[] WSMethod(@WebParam(name="arg0") String arg0)
}
```

WS implementation:

```
@WebService
@Stateless
public class WSImpl extends GenericSessionBean implements WSInterface {
    @WebMethod
    public String[] WSMethod( String arg0)
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

And i need to get client IP in WSMethod.
I tried to get it by this way (it works in "common" webservice):

```
@Resource  
private SessionContext ctx;  
public String[] getProperties() {  
    List propList = new ArrayList();    
    MessageContext mc = ctx.getMessageContext();  
    Iterator props = mc.getPropertyNames();  
    for (String prop = (String)props.next(); props.hasNext(); prop = (String)props.next())  
        { propList.add(prop); }  
    return propList.toArray(new String[propList.size()]);
}
```

But no success: there is no property with name `REMOTE_ADDR` in `MessageContext`.

Is there any way to get `REMOTE_ADDR` in `@Stateless` EJB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to obtain a WebServiceContext instead of SessionContext with @Resource? I've no appropriate env to check it up right now

Comment: @Resource
private WebServiceContext ctx;
...
MessageContext mc = ctx.getMessageContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST));
String clientIP = request.getRemoteAddr();

Comment: It's so strange, but now your solution works!
I remember that earlier i already tried WebServiceContext, but compiler give me an error. Now it works as needed. Thanks!